# Play a video based on a value from local storage

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I am aware that this question might have been asked here a few times, however I could not find a solution I've been looking for. We have a requirement where the users should be able to pause the video and resume from where they left.

I was able to get to the point where I am able to store and fetch the paused time from local storage, however I have been facing challenges playing the video from the stored value. Below is the code.

```html
<video id="myVideo" width="300" height="300" controls>
    <source src="Bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video><br />

<button onclick="PlayVideo()" type="button" id="PlayVideo">Play</button>

<script>
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo")

    function getCurTime() {
        return vid.currentTime
    }

    var isPlaying = false
    var PausedTime

    function PlayVideo() {
        var change = document.getElementById("PlayVideo")

        if (isPlaying) {
            vid.pause()

            //Storing the paused time to local storage
            localStorage.setItem('CaptureTime', getCurTime())

            //Get the saved time from local storage
            PausedTime = localStorage.getItem('CaptureTime')
            change.innerHTML = "Play"
        }

        else {

            vid.play()
            change.innerHTML = "Pause"
        }
        isPlaying = !isPlaying

    }
</script>
```

Would appreciate if anyone here could help me out with this.
Please let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you tried `vid.currentTime = PausedTime` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only get the time when playing, and save on pause. Set the current time to the local storage paused time when being played. Like this:

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function getCurTime() { 
  return vid.currentTime;
} 

var isPlaying = false;
var PausedTime;

function PlayVideo() {
    var change = document.getElementById("PlayVideo");
    //Get the saved time from local storage
    var PausedTime = localStorage.getItem('CaptureTime');
   
    if (isPlaying) {
      vid.pause();
    
      //Storing the paused time to local storage
      localStorage.setItem('CaptureTime', getCurTime());
      
      change.innerHTML = "Play"; 
    }

    else {
      vid.currentTime = PausedTime;
      vid.play();
      change.innerHTML = "Pause";  
    }
    
    isPlaying = !isPlaying;    

}
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" width="300" height="300" controls>
  <source src="Bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video><br/>

<button onclick="PlayVideo()" type="button" id="PlayVideo">Play</button>
```

Comment: If the user wants to use his/her own control buttons, you should remove "controls" from the video tag.

Comment: Michael Thank you for the update and the code seems to be running fine as expected

@AdamG , Thank you for the inputs , can pause/resume on refresh be achieved on the default controls attribute?

Answer (score 0):

To pause and play a video in javascript you don't actually *need* to save the time to local storage.
That being said, if you still want to do it that way, you would just need to remember these lines:

```
localStorage.setItem('CaptureTime', getCurTime());
PausedTime = localStorage.getItem('CaptureTime');
vid.currentTime = PausedTime;
```

[*for reference*](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp)

---

In addition, when I tried your code it wouldn't change the play to pause, so I made a few adjustments.

This is how I implemented it all:

```js
<html> 
<body> 
        
        <button id="controls" onclick="play()" type="button">Play Video</button><br> 
        
        <video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176">
          <source src="Bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
        
    <script> 
        var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 
        var isPlaying = false; //or this could be: var isPaused = vid.paused;
        
        function play() { 

            if(!isPlaying){
               vid.play(); 
               document.getElementById("controls").innerHTML = "Pause Video";
            }
            else{
                vid.pause(); 
                document.getElementById("controls").innerHTML = "Play Video";
            }
            isPlaying = !isPlaying;
         } 
     </script> 
    
        
 </body> 
 </html>
```

Check out these pages for more:

- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_play.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: thank you for the answer. Does this code handle resuming the video from where we last left?

Comment: Yes, unless you are planning on resuming after a refresh or reload of the page. In that situation you'd probably need to save the current time to something.

Comment: Thank you for the response Adam , I wish to make the video player similar to YouTube player i.e. it should play from last left irrespective of the device browser. Can you suggest where this needs to be stored? and what is the best way of achieving this?